# how do i fix it (arduino)

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266wifi

i want to use AT command
but i cant
i use esp8266 wifi shield model
and i connected jumper line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wn42.png)

but

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(0,1); //RX, TX

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   mySerial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
if(mySerial.available())
{
  Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
if(Serial.available())
{
  mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
}
```

After uploading, there is no response even if I input to the serial monitor.
i had AT command firmware updated

im bad at english sorry

Comment: pins 0 and 1 are hardware Serial of Uno and connected to the USB chip. use different pins for SoftwareSerial

Comment: So may I ask for a picture of how to wire it?

Comment: i use arduino uno and esp8266 wifi shield but i dont know what use wire sorry about that i am beginner